# Метод text (jquery) символ '\n' воспринимает как пробел

Tags: jquery, текст, символы

```
$('#news_title').keyup(function(){               
    var s = $(this).val();
        $('#format').text(s);

   $( "#format" ).text(function( index, s ) {       
            s = s.split(" ").join('\n');//соединяет пробелом
      //s = s.split(" ").join('Ёлка');//соединяет Ёлкой
            return s; 
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/L8r0yk5x/

При этом если вместо .text метод .val (cответственно, вместо div второй textarea), \n воспрининимается как перенос.

Comment: а вопрос то в чем?

Answer (score 3):

> При этом если вместо .text метод .val (cответственно, вместо div второй textarea), \n воспрининимается как перенос.

Если надо отразить `\n` в `HTML`, то это `<br>`.

```js
$('#news_title').keyup(function(){               
    var s = $(this).val();
  $('#format').text(s);
  
   $( "#format" ).html(function( index, s ) {  
   //s = s.split("\n").join('<br>');//соединяет \n с <br>
   return s.replace(/\n/, '<br>'); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="news_title"></textarea></br>

<div id="format" ></div>
```

---

```js
// @MedvedevDev
$('#news_title').keyup(function() {
  var s = $(this).val();
  $("#format").html(s.replace(/\s/g, '<br>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="news_title"></textarea></br>

<div id="format"></div>
```

Comment: Не совсем ((. Надо, чтобы в id="format" введенный пользователем после пробела текст переносился на новую строку, у Вас одной строкой( С '<br>' тоже экспериментировала. Прям так и вставляет голый <br> между кусками текста.

Comment: @Наташа, вместо `.text` используйте `.html`

Comment: @Наташа у меня одной строкой? в моем проимере вместо `text(...)`, `html(...)`.

Comment: сплит, джоин ... логичнее наверное реплейс?

Comment: @MedvedevDev логиченее =)

Comment: `$('#news_title').keyup(function(){ var s = $(this).val(); $( "#format").html(s.replace(/\s/g, '<br>')); });` ;)

Comment: @MedvedevDev добавил ваш вариант :)

Comment: Это был не вариант, а правка))) Ваш код не работает xDD